# geometry.mergeVertices() only at render time

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to merge vertices only at render time?  I'm doing a series of morphs which requires the vertex list to stay the same, however I want to merge the vertices to get a smooth reflection on a cube camera.  Any one aware of a command similar to unmerge vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is not in the documentation section, but you need to use the explode modifier as demonstrated in this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_tessellation

```
var explodeModifier = new THREE.ExplodeModifier();
explodeModifier.modify( geometry );
geometry.computeFaceNormals(); 
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
//This will undo the geometry.mergeVertices();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it? It should work. 
You'll need to call

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate()
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate()
```

to tell three.js that the vertices and faces, respectively, have changed. There are other update functions you may need to call too (for instance if normals have changed). More details here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Note the comment on that page that the total number of vertices can't change. This may require you to do the merge on a temp geometry and then copy the vertices to your rendered geometry.